# Where did the "What's off-topic" list go?

Tags: support, on-topic-definition, meta-faq

I think all the SE sites used to have a `/faq` that included a bullet list of topics that should be covered by the site, along with things that *shouldn't* be covered by the site.  Now, `/faq` redirects to `/tour` which only gives the "glossy brochure" overview of how SE sites work, generally.

Maybe the better question is: where do I go to find out what SE site I should ask my question on?

Comment: `/faq` was replaced with `/help`: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @YannisRizos: Why doesn't it redirect there?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Because SE thought it would be a better idea to redirect it to `/tour` (which has a link to the help center at the bottom). Personally, I'd redirect it to `/help`, `/tour` is only useful for brand new users (who probably have no idea the `/faq` route ever existed). That said, our on and off topic lists do show up in `/tour` (somewhere in the middle).

Comment: Yannis, my eyes ran *right* over that bit in the middle.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of topics for each site should be on [`/help/on-topic`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Questions asking which site to ask on are on-topic for the Meta sites. If you think your question might be on-topic for XX.SE, you should ask in meta.XX.SE if you are right in your assessment.
If you don't have a clue which site to ask on, ask for a site recommendation at [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation).